# How wait for responses in asyncio before continuing inside an event loop?

Tags: python, asynchronous, websocket, python-asyncio

I am working with the asyncio and websockets packages in Python 3.6 with the simple aim of writing a script that will:
(1) connect to a websocket;
(2) send multiple subscription messages; 
(3) await a response; and 
(3) push the response to MongoDB.

I am dealing with numerous websockets so I'm trying to use asyncio to replicate a degree of parallelism and my headache begins.

Using asynchronous packages like motor and websockets, I have been able to write a script that completes this task; however, I am writing duplicates to my database. I believe the cause is my scheduling strucutre in asyncio, with writes to MongoDB able to occur numerous times before a new message is received. Thus, I would like to add a degree of blocking within the event loop to ensure that my asynchronous updates to MongoDB are not executed prior to my result variable being updated with new data.

I was able to get the general outcome working; however, the script was storing duplicates. I believe this was due to the fact that the await process on my asynchronous data pushing function (update_MonogoDB) would complete multiple times in the loop before new messages were received. Thus, my aim is to try and block my asynchronous code at the point of message receipt so that I can be sure that new message data is available before writing to MongoDB. I can't just use synchronous code in this case as i'm opening up the connections all asynchronously.

I understand that the event loop has blocking properties, but I can't seem to write a nested event loop to create this blocking. Thus, I have tried to write the event loop within a thread.

**Is there a better way to doing this - how do i block an asynchronous function within an event loop?**

```
import websockets, asyncio, ast, threading
import motor.asycnio

async def WebSocketConn(url, subscription_msg):
    #Establishing the connection and sending subscription messages
    async with websockets.connect(url) as ws:
        data = {}
        print("Sending subscription")
        await ws.send(json.dumps(subscribe))

        #Defining message collection process
        async def collect_msg():
        try:
            msg = await asyncio.wait_for(ws.recv(), timeout=20)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            try:
                print('Connection timeout - pinging')
                pong_waiter = await ws.ping()
                await asyncio.wait_for(pong_waiter, timeout=10)
            except:
                print('Connection Failed within collect_msg()')

        print("Starting message collection loop")
        while True:
            #create a new loop
            new_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()

            #assign the loop to another thread
            t = threading.Thread(target=start_new_loop(new_loop))
            t.start()

            #assign some async work to the new thread
            future = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(collect_msg(), 
            new_loop)
            msg = future.result()    #need blocking on this message
            result = ast.literal_eval(msg)

            await update_MongoDB(result)

async def MultipleConns(conn_details:list):coroutines = 
[WebSocketConn(input[0], input[1], input[2]) for input conn_details] 
completed, pending = await asyncio.wait(coroutines)                             
return completed                                                                

main_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(main_loop)
main_loop.set_debug(True)

try:
    main_loop.run_until_complete(MultipleConns(details))
finally:
    main_loop.close()
```

Comment: Did you try [synchronization primitives](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html)?

Comment: Thanks, i'm looking into queues at the moment and seeing if a producer/consumer style approach will overcome this. My issue stems from me trying to keep the asycnio websockets connection open while in my event loop it seams.

Comment: I can't seem to add a queue inside my event loop... TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of '_WindowsSelectorEventLoop'